# sending pdf to a printer / binder service

Tags: overleaf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

I wrote my thesis in LaTeX using overleaf. I compile the pdf and open with adobe acrobat pro. I then apply pdf/x standards and make sure all my fonts are embedded. Everything checks out and no errors are thrown.

I've also printed the pdf with my school's printer. And everything looks good.
I've uploaded it to a printing and book binding service and we've been troubleshooting issues for several weeks and we're still finding they're not able to print my .pdf. The best they can tell me is that: "Customer created the pdf using GPL Ghostscript, and this could be our issue. Historically, I don’t think files made using GPL work particularly well in our workflow. Too many differences in what it’s doing with postscript vs. Adobe, which is what our prepress and presses are based around."
Could this error be unique to this specific printing service? Or Is it unlikely that trying another printer/binder service would be able to print if I don't address the issue?

Sorry, I don't know what information is relevant to provide. Or where to even start with troubleshooting.

Thank you.

Comment: Change printer/binder.

Comment: as you have acrobat pro you should also have distiller and could process the postscript with it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was going to suggest that but getting the ps from overleaf isn't completely trivial (needs a custom latexmkrc I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle isn't it kept as auxiliary file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's not in their other files menu, I think latexmk deletes it after running pstopdf

Comment: Processing PostScript might not work as expected, if the OP actually needs PDF/X. Outside the scope of TeX. "It depends on other factors."

Comment: @rallg if the current ps2pdf conversion of the dvips produced ps  meets pdf/x then I think it must have enough pdfmark in it for distiller to do the same. Admitedly it's harder to make good pdf going via dvi ->ps->pdf but that's the route already being taken

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, dvips. I thought the requested file was "postscript" as mentioned above, *.ps. In any case, PDF/X has certain image requirements that probably are not processed via TeX. Outside the scope of character glyphs and placement. This is why Acrobat Pro (with Adobe image processing) and Distiller (without) are different. Anyway, are we sure that the OP meant PDF/X, rather than PDF/A? Common misunderstandng.  Also, Acrobat Pro can be configured, regarding what it tests.

Comment: @rallg  "are we sure" no:-)

Comment: Sorry for the trivial question: could package `pdfx` help to compile directly a pdf/x document, without need of reprocessing the file with Acrobat Pro?

Comment: Can't you also use Preflight in Acrobat Pro to transform your tex-PDF into a X-conform PDF?

Comment: There are printing services that specialize in (PhD) theses, those deal with LaTeX-generated pdfs every day and they know exactly what to do to preprocess your file(s) to make them ready for printing. Try to find one of those, maybe ask other students or professors for some names if you are unsure how to find them.

Comment: I is NOT the case that package `pdfx` will always help. The reason is that the package does not inspect graphics or vector images (unlike Acrobat Pro, which can do that). If at all possible, use a graphics program to pre-process all diagrams and included PDf into flat raster png. Strip color profile.That might help. But you are in territory that is based addressed by a graphic artist. Doubt that either TeX or Ghosctscript is the problem. If the printer says that Ghoscript is a problem, more likely it is the case that Ghoscript is only used by those without graphics training.